# How do I build a plugin that converts an array to a datafile and vice versa?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

So i've been asked to build a plugin that converts an array (I guess taken from user input) and converts it into a datafile and vice versa.

I'm not sure how I would convert the array to datafile and vice versa, would this be something downloaded by the user, and uploaded by the user?

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <h1>arraytodatafile</h1>
        <input type="text" id="userInput"></input>
        <button onClick="arrayBuild()">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var userInput = [];

function arrayBuild(){
    var currentInput = document.getElementById("userInput").innerHTML();
    userInput.push(currentInput);
}

console.log(userInput);
```

index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: arraytodatafile
 * Plugin URI: http://www.mywebsite.com/my-first-plugin
 * Description: Exports array to data file, vice versa.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Steven Curnow
 * Author URI: codexx1.000webhostapp.com
 */

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'displayHTMLpage' );

function displayHTMLpage() {
    include( 'index.html' );
}

?>
```

Comment: Indeed: [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is not a function. (Also, please [don't ask multiple questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371614/why-isnt-it-good-to-ask-multiple-questions-and-answers-in-one-question) at once.)

Comment: did you mean `userInput.push(...)`

Comment: When I console.log(userInput) it shows empty array, why is this?